# How to get alternate background color as a particular color in RTF

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

In the RTF template, I want the alternate rows to have a light green color, when I am using the below tag, I am getting all rows with green and text background as green, not the entire row-

```
  <?if@row:position() mod 2=0?>
<xsl:attribute name="background-color">#e9f7ef</xsl:attribute>
 <?end if?>
```

I saw in the Oracle doc the below used -

```
<?if@row:position() mod 2=0?> <xsl:attribute name="background-color" xdofo:ctx="incontext">lightgray</xsl:attribute><?end if?>
```

but as soon as i add xdofo:ctx="incontext", i do not get any output at all.

How to get alternate background color as a particular color.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me. Make sure you are putting it in a field, and the field is within the `for-each` tag

[image]